# Fastest way to search in a BLOB - Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I know that searching a text in a BLOB is this way in an oracle database

```
select *
  from table1
 where dbms_lob.instr (t1, -- the blob
                   utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('foo'), -- the search string cast to raw
                   1, -- where to start. i.e. offset
                   1 -- Which occurrance i.e. 1=first
                    ) > 0 -- location of occurrence. Here I don't care.  Just find any
;
```

credit @Olafur Tryggvason

But it's very slow,  I takes than 10 minutes !

Is there a faster way to search text in a BLOB ?

PS : I'm using JDBC to consume this database

Thanks

Comment: Use Oracle Text and index the blob column?

Comment: @MT0 : I've seen that it works only with word and PDF docs, not sure if it's compatible, do you have a tuto for this ?

Comment: If the BLOB is neither a Word document nor a PDF what is it?

Comment: Probably and XML

Comment: A binary XML? hmmmm

Comment: Yes, probably a binary xml, i can read it with java using byte[]

Comment: You should be able to build a Text index on a binary XML document. So try it. The problem is CTXSYS indexes aren't maintained transactionally; so there will be a lag between inserting an XML document and being able to retrieve it through a Text search.